# How to get attribute value for disabled element in Angular JS application

Tags: javascript, java, angular, selenium-webdriver

I need to get attribute value of a disabled element during run time and assert its value.

My current code looks like this but is not returning a value:

```
softAssert.assertFalse(shrSub.nextButton().waitForPresent().getAttributeValue("disabled").equals(true), "Next button must be disabled");
```

Tried find the value returned by .getAttributeValue("disabled") but it is coming as null.

```
String test = shrSub.nextButton().waitForPresent().getAttributeValue("disabled"); 
System.out.println(test);
```

`shrSub` is the class object reference for the webpage.

The element properties are as follows:

```
<button _ngcontent-nnr-c51="" class="share-button mat-button" mat-button="" matsteppernext="" disabled="" type="submit">
    <span class="mat-button-wrapper">NEXT</span>
    <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
    <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

Please help me find the right attribute value for this disabled element so that I can assert successfully during run time.

I am expecting some attribute value for disabled field (true or false) to get fetched which can then be compared with expected value.

Comment: Did you try with isEnabled() method? that returns a boolean.

Comment: So are you using angular or angularjs? Your question says angularjs, but you have tagged angular?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your DOM, this is right because the `disabled` attribute has no value in it. 
When it is converting it from HTML to your coding language, it is becoming null.

Can you try following:

```
softAssert.assertFalse(shrSub.nextButton().waitForPresent().getAttributeValue("disabled").equals(null), "Next button must be disabled");
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that work around which worked.. Thanks @work_ishaan